# A good guide to read about HTML / CSS that well covers aligning

Tags: html, css

It is not my first day building pages in HTML / CSS, but still every now and then my head breaks on how to align all elements (e.g. of the form or a page) the way I want.
**Particularly that I don't want to use absolute values when I build/design a page.** With absolute values I could place everything where I want, but **my goal is to being able to align all elements without hardcoding absolute positions** (or at least only using the very minimum of that).
Can you recommend any online resource that teaches how to do it well? If not teaching, then at least good to use for my purposes?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: -1 Closed as off topic for solely asking a reference. But actually, your question is too brood: it is impossible to address every single aspect within your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason why you asked this question is because you care about responsive design, and you don't want to be hard coding all of your elements positions (you can correct me if I am wrong).

Here is a little site I found with tons of great examples.

http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html

I would suggest you study the source to learn all the great techniques of responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Should have everything you need. DON'T USE FLOATS unless you've spent hours trying an alternative with no avail! Anything you need to float, 99.9% of the time can be done with inline block! I say do not use floats because floats override several CSS rules and break the hierarchy that is the entire point of "cascading" stylesheets. They are a bandaid fix that TYPICALLY, imo, are indicative that an inferior design was chosen, because I do not know of anything you really need to float except for very specialized things like a temporary ad button or something.

To make inline block compatible in IE7 btw, add: `*display:inline; zoom:1;`

TLDR summary of that article:

Use `block;` and `inline-block;` to position. When elements align weirdly with `inline-block;`, use `vertical-align:top;` or `bottom;` or `middle;`

To center things, put them in a container of set `width` (or `width:100%;`), and then apply `margin:auto;` to the centered element.

**if you disagree that's fine, please provide reasoning!**

Comment: DON'T USE FLOATS ... you may want to explain your point. why not?

Comment: @Danko good point, I added my reasoning